# Calculating all possible combinations for binomial coefficients in Python?

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list with about 120 items and I need to check every possible different combination of half the list, so 60 items, where the order doesn't matter. So the number of those combinations should be 120!/(60!*60!). The problem is, I need to check every combination, since I want to find the "best" one for a problem. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

(If you're interested,my problem goes as follows:
At my school, half of the people have school this week, the other ones next week, and then we have it again this week, etc. Problem is, this was divided at random, so some classes have an unproportional amount of students (classes are 25 each, so one class fe has 19 students in week 1 and 6 in week 2). So, I wanted to find the best way to divide the students, in total we're about 120, so that every class has about half the original amount. My idea was to make a list for every class with their students in it, and check the proportions for each combination of the total, subtract 0.5 from each class proportion, and sum the absolute value of the difference for each class. The combination with the lowest sum is then the best, since the classes are then the most evenly divided.)

Comment: There is a method in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) module to enumerate combinations. However, there are 96614908840363322603893139521372656 such combinations... You will have to find another way. First, describe more precisely your problem, as it's quite unclear.

Comment: Ya, scipy.special.binom(120,60) has 119 binary digits. That's like getting close to things like "number of atoms in the solar system" type stuff. Meaning even if you were a type 2 civilization, you probably couldn't iterate over all combinations.

Comment: If you could be a *lot* more specific about what "best" means for the division of students and what "proportions" you're talking about, etc. etc. then it might be possible to come up with a smarter way to approach the problem. But regardless it seems that you don't really have a programming question at the moment, but a general sort of problem-solving question.

Answer (score 0):

The function below will return every possible combination of items in a list while each combination will have items by the length of your list (i.e. 120):

```
from itertools import product

def algorithm(myList):
    possible = [''.join(combination) for combination in product(myList, repeat= len(myList))]
    return possible
print(algorithm(myList))
```

Note that the function above will allow only for combination of length equals to your list length, if you want to allow for additional combinatioins of lower than 120, the below should do:

```
def algorithm(myList):
    allPoss = list()
    for i in range(1, len(myList)+1):
        possible = [''.join(combination) for combination in product(myList, repeat= i)]
        allPoss.append(possible)
    return allPoss
print(algorithm(myList))
```

You mentioned you want to do half of the list:

> combination of half the list, so 60 items

Now i'm not exactly sure what you mean by that?

1- do you have spicific 60 items you want the combination for? Then create a sublist for those 60 items and run through the functions above.

2- do you want the combination to have only 60 items? Use first function but pass `repeat = 60`.

3- any other possible interpretation? let me know!

Did i completely misunderstood your question and my answer is pointless? Apologies, try explaining it again!

**EDIT:**
I've just realised that the above functions allow for repeatitions of items within the combination, if you don't want to allow for that, you can try something like this where again you can adjust `range(0,len(vals)` to 60 if you want only 60 length combinations or to `range(0,(len(vals)/2)` to allow for additional combinations of lower than 60:

```
import itertools

def generate(vals):
    return ("".join(x) for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(vals,i+1) for i in range(0,len(vals))))
print(list(generate("".join(myList))))
```

**2nd Edit: This should do the trick then:**

```
import itertools

def generate(vals):
    return ("".join(x) for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(vals,i+1) for i in range(0,60)))
combinations = list(generate("".join(myList)))

#to keep those of 60 length:
result = [item for item in combinations if len(item)==60]
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying, yes, I meant that each combination should only have 60 items, or half the length of the original list. So for the list [1,2,3,4],the combinations would be [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]

Comment: I've updated the answer for a second edit according to my understanding, try this and see if it's what you want!