# Generating a list of lists whose elements come from another list (Python)

Tags: python, list

How can you generate a list of lists, with varying sizes, whose elements are from another list, say, `a = [1,2,3]`? Ex: If I choose length of the lists to be 2, then I should get `[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]`.

Comment: `import itertools; list(itertools.product([1, 2, 3], repeat=2))`

Comment: For size n: `n = 3; [[i, j] for i in range(1, n+1) for j in range(1, n+1)]`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called 'binomial combinations', you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61738593/calculating-all-possible-combinations-for-binomial-coefficients-in-python) to learn more about it but this code should work with combinations of 2:

```
def algorithm(myList):
    possible = [''.join(combination) for combination in product(myList, repeat= 2)]
    return possible
print(algorithm(myList))
```